# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Gson using Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gson, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to use the GSON library to parse a JSON file in my Maven project. I've added the following dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using IntelliJ and my code looks like this:

```
import com.google.gson.*;

public class Import {
    Gson gson = new Gson();}
```

However, when I run the code, I'm getting the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`

I'm not sure what's causing this error. How can I resolve this issue and use the GSON library in my project?

Comment: Can you provide the whole stacktrace, pelase?

Comment: You can try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.